# Swift arabic version, delaying happening after click back or push a view controller, in the navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, combine

After changing language from English to arabic the application has a delay in the navigation,
the implication implemented with Combine and there is a Language Manager file when changing the
language it do some changing directions,

I tried to remove the implemented localization and add LanguageManager_iOS library to handle it
but the same issue happens,

here example of using combine

```
    var page = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(1)
    private var bindings = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    var hasMorePages = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(true)
    private var provider: CommunityAPIProtocol?
    provider?.getForYouPosts(page: page.value, search: search, categoryId: categoryId).receive(on: RunLoop.main)
                .sink(receiveCompletion: requestCompletionHandler, receiveValue: {[weak self] in
                    if let data = $0.data?.docs {
                        if self?.page.value == 1 {
                            self?.posts.value = data
                        } else {
                            self?.posts.value.append(contentsOf: data)
                        }
                    }
                    self?.hasMorePages.value = $0.data?.hasNextPage ?? false
                }).store(in: &bindings)
```

this is an example of methods in Localization file

```
// set language for localization
func setLanguage(language: Language, reloadApp: Bool = false) -> Void {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(language.rawValue, forKey: languageKey)
    let path: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: language.rawValue, ofType: "lproj")
    if path == nil {
        //in case the language does not exists
        resetLocalization()
    }
    else {
        bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    resetApp(reloadApp: reloadApp)
}

// reset app for the new lang
private func resetApp(reloadApp: Bool) {
    let dir = getLanguageDirection()
    let semantic: UISemanticContentAttribute = dir == .leftToRight ? .forceLeftToRight : .forceRightToLeft
    UITabBar.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = semantic
    UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = semantic
    UINavigationBar.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = semantic
    UIPageControl.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    UICollectionView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = semantic
    UITextView.appearance().textAlignment = dir == .leftToRight ? .left : .right
    UITextField.appearance().textAlignment = dir == .leftToRight ? .left : .right
    UISearchBar.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = semantic
    UISwitch.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    UIPageControl.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = semantic
    delegate?.resetApp(reloadApp: reloadApp)
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to manually set language inside the app instead of relying on iOS?

Comment: I don’t know as I already found it like this, should i change it instead of finding a solution for it @lazarevzubov

Comment: If the language change was already in the app, when you joined it, I suppose it used to work, right? So, you did something that broke it. Then, you can investigate the history of changes to find the commit that broke the functionality. Or doesn't it work from the beginning, and your task is to finish the implementation? In this case, I would question the UX and suggest automatic language switching that iOS offers to the apps out-of-the-box.

Comment: Unfortunately, they were having this delay from the beginning, 
I will try to use the automatic language switching from ios side as you said @lazarevzubov